# Angular2: access one of multiple child components by css class

Tags: angular

For example, if I have this structure:

```
<parent-component>
    <child-a class="a"></child-a>
    <child-a class="b selected"></child-a>
    <child-b class="c"></child-b>
    <child-b class="d"></child-b>
    ...
</parent-component>
```

How do I access the instance of ChildA with class ".selected" in my ParentComponent?

EDIT:
In ParentComponent I have a list of 10 objects (in property `items`), and in its template I loop over the `items` array, and create ChildA or ChildB component for every item (whether ChildA or ChildB depends on some config in item).

Then by clicking on any item I mark it as 'selected' (the corresponding object in the `items` is stored as `selectedItem`). Later I need to access the component, that corresponds to the `selectedItem` (and has ".selected" class").

Comment: It's unclear what you asking. Create a plunk and clarify your specific problem.

Comment: Don't think you can select a child component by it's class without just querying the dom. You could give it a name and use `@ContentChild` to select it. e.g. `<child-component-a #childB class="b"></child-component-a>`

Comment: @RomanC updated question with some more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `@ContentChild` or `@ContentChildren` in your parent.

For example:
In your case use:
`@ContentChildren(ChildComponentA) childs: QueryList<ChildComponentA>;`
and u got all childs
now just simple iterate.

For more information go here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ContentChildren-decorator.html

---

EDIT:
You can use `ElementRef` in child to detect selected class, here you are an example:

[plunkr here](https://plnkr.co/edit/nihAWwLXvzMpuhVx4LSp?p=preview)
it is this what do u want to do ??

Comment: and what about the ".selected" class?

Comment: the best way (for now and for me) is add property to child-N, `isSelected`, and check it when iterate trought component query list

Comment: @eagor i update my answer, i add solution using `ElementRef` it help you ?